# React-Leaflet : Calculate actual camera height from the ground based on zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

**Is it possible to get the height of the leaflet's 'camera' from the ground, based on the zoom level?**

[image]

If you look at the screenshot above (taken from a movie), I am trying to achieve the same result in the red circle, which is displaying at what height the 'camera' is at on the current zoom level.

I've tried to search for a solution for this, but couldn't find any. Keywords used such as 'height', 'zoom level', 'elevation' yielded results that were either to calculate the height of the map canvas, or the topographic elevation.

What I am looking for is how to calculate the hypothetical height from the ground to where the 'camera' (or users viewing the map). My thinking is that this can somehow be achieved via referencing to the zoom level.

Is there a way to achieve this using `react-leaflet`?

Comment: This concept will break down at lower zoom levels.  Are you assuming the camera height is the distance from the camera to the center of the map?  At lower zoom levels, the center from the 'camera' to the distance of the map is *very different* from the distance to somewhere not at the center.  I would try this question over at the [gis stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), the folks over there are very knowledgeable about these kinds of things

Comment: Found this for you: [What ratio scales do Google Maps zoom levels correspond to?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387562/150632) - the answer linked here has a formula for height, given zoom and latitude

Comment: Thank @SethLutske for pointing in the right direction. I've posted the answer here so that others can benefit from it too.

Comment: I am confused about the "altitude" of the "view point": the extent of what we see in the viewport would depend on the "camera" focal length. By changing that focal length, you can "zoom" without changing your position. So we must assume a fixed focal length, and choose an arbitrary value. By doing that, we have a fixed angle of view, and the "altitude" becomes a simple ratio of the map scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @SethLutske for pointing to the right direction. The actual answer can be found on the gis.stackexchange : [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to/387562#387562)

```
const EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 6371010
const TILE_SIZE = 256
const SCREEN_PIXEL_HEIGHT = 768

const RADIUS_X_PIXEL_HEIGHT = 27.3611 * EARTH_RADIUS_IN_METERS * SCREEN_PIXEL_HEIGHT

const altitude = (zoom, latitude) => (RADIUS_X_PIXEL_HEIGHT * Math.cos((latitude * Math.PI) / 180)) / (Math.pow(2, zoom) * TILE_SIZE)
```

There's actually a lot of discussion related to the topic in the gis.stackexchange link above, but I choose this, as rightfully pointed out by @sethluske and it worked well with `react-leaflet`.